# How can i solve a "Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element' error?

Tags: javascript, angular

I really need help to solve this error. I wrote the following JavaScript code below to enable my tab indicator to show on a clicked tab when clicked on but all I am getting is an error which says: "Property 'style' doesn't exist on type 'Element'". The tabs work perfectly fine, I can switch from one tab to the other. I have seen similar questions but my issue wasn't resolved following their lead suggestions. I am currently building an angular project and i wrote my JavaScript in the ngInit(){} function in my .ts file. The code is below:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let tabPanes = this._class('tab-header')[0].getElementsByTagName('div');

    for (let i = 0; i < tabPanes.length; i++) {
      tabPanes[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        this._class('tab-header')[0]
          .getElementsByClassName('active')[0]
          .classList.remove('active');
          tabPanes[i].classList.add("active");

          this._class('tab-indicator')[0].style.top = 'calc(80px + ${i*50}px)'; // This flags a "property 'style' doe not exist on type 'Element'" error.

          this._class('tab-content')[0]
          .getElementsByClassName('active')[0]
          .classList.remove('active');

          this._class('tab-content')[0]
          .getElementsByTagName('div')[i]
          .classList.add('active');
      });
    }
  }

_class(name: any) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(name);
  }
```

Where did i go wrong? Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: you can do as aakash garg answered, or, create a class that contains the style you wanted, and add with classList.add, I'm suggesting this, because it will be easier if you ever want to remove thee style

Comment: @Vintage, it's **not** an "Angular way". You should avoid use adEventListener(click). Why not create a variable "index" in .html and use e.g. for the fisrt tab '(click)="index=0"` and [class.active]="index==0"? Remember: Angular relation variables in .ts (the model) with the .html (the view). So you can change the attributes of the .html using variables.

Comment: @Eliseo Can you point me to an example? To your point, i have used addEventListener() function before and i have never had a problem with it in angular.

Comment: When I say that it's **not** an Angular way, I don't want to say that not work else you're not using all the tools that Angular has. You're in Angular, but not using Angular. I don't know about your tab, so I made a simple ( * )[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qhmayb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). The "magic" is relation variables and attributes. ( * ) really we should use a *ngFor, it's only you can see the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollectionOf<Element>` . There is no `style` property on Element type and hence the error.

You can type cast it to collection of HTMLElement and that should resolve the issue:

```ts
_class(name: any): HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement> {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(name) as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
}
```

**PS:** Though the above should resolve the typescript error, but as Eliseo mentioned in one of the comments, you can make use of Angular [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding#event-binding) and [property binding to class attribute](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#binding-to-the-class-attribute) to do it Angular way.

Comment: I was trying your suggestion before i saw it here and truly, the error was resolved. The only issue i have is that despite the error been resolved, the tab indicator which should move to a tab when clicked is still not moving.

Comment: It's difficult to say without looking at the html code. But one issue I could observe which you would need to fix is wrapping of the `calc` function within back-ticks rather than single quotes. Proper way of usage: `\`calc(80px + ${i*50}px)\``

Comment: Thanks Siddhant. It worked perfectly. Apologies for the delay. I was preoccupied with some things.

Answer (score 0):

Change _class method to :-

```
_class(name: any): NodeList<HTMLElement> {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(name) as NodeList<HTMLElement>;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it threw this error:

Conversion of type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>' to type 'HTMLElement' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 275 more.ts(2352)

Comment: updated the answer please try.

Comment: It threw this error: Type 'NodeList' is not generic .ts(2315).